# How could the linear transformation of a set $S$ include $S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume I have a set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|\|x\|_\infty\leq1\}$ and a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, I wonder under what condition of $A$ that the set $S_1=\{Ax|x\in S\}$ includes $S$, i.e., $S\subseteq S_1$?

I know $A$ must be full rank, and should be 'large' enough. Because I can multiple $A$ by a sufficiently large scalar, which will make the above relation holds. But I wonder how it relates to the structure of $A$, for example, the norm or the eigenvalue of $A$. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Polar decomposition. Further hint: linear transformations can only on euclidean spaces may only dilate, rotate, mirror.

Comment: I have checked the Polar decomposition but still don't know how to start. Actually I want to judge whether a matrix satisfies this condition by its norm or eigenvalues, could you elaborate more on it？

Comment: For reasons of convexity  it should suffice to check that the "upper" half of corners of the hypercube $S$ are in there. I don't recall ever having solved this problem even in the simplest case of $n=2$. Hmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is that $\|x\|_{\infty }\leq 1\Rightarrow \exists y \in S$ such that $Ay=x$. As you said, it implies that $A$ is surjective, and hence injective. In particular it is invertible, so that $Ay=x$ is equivalent to $y=A^{-1}x$; therefore your the condition is equivalent to $\|x\|_\infty \leq 1\Rightarrow \|A^{-1}x\|_\infty\leq 1$, or in other words $\|A^{-1}\|_{\infty}\leq 1$. This implies that $\|A\|_{\infty}\geq 1$, but this is not a sufficient condition!

Note that the eigenvalues of $A$ are exactly the inverses of the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$. The condition $\|A^{-1}\|_{\infty}\leq 1$ therefore implies that all of the eigenvalues of $A$ must be greater than or equal to $1$ in absolute value.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea about a sufficient condition?

Comment: The condition that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\geq 1$ is stronger than the condition than $\|A\|_{\infty}$, but I don't think it would be enough to give you $\|A^{-1}\|_{\infty}\leq 1$ (even assuming $A$ is diagonalizable). Perhaps you could get something using some inequality between the $\infty$-norm and the $1$ or the $2$-norm, though.